# Searching for the maximum of a (strictly convex) two-dimensional distribution via maximization over a series of arbitrarily specified 1D intervals

Tags: pr.probability, convex-optimization

Let $f$ be a strictly convex two-dimensional distribution with a maximum $M$ at some unknown position $(x_m,y_m)$.  Starting from the origin, $(x_0,y_0) = (0,0)$, we need to find $(x_m,y_m)$, however we can only perform an "oracle-like" query where we ask for the maximum value of $f(x,y)$ along some one-dimensional interval defined and bounded by the coordinates $[c_1,c_2]$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are specified as desired.  The "oracle" also returns slightly noisy information s.t. the coordinate $(x_i,y_i)$ claimed to maximize $f$ along the one-dimensional interval is only guaranteed to be within some fraction $\omega$ of the intervals true maximum.  In other words, letting $h_i$ be the maximum value of $f$ along the given 1D interval, we're only guaranteed that $f(x_i,y_i) \leq (\omega \times h_i)$.

Again letting $M$ be the true maximum of the strictly convex two-dimensional distribution $f$, and attempting to most efficiently use "oracle" queries, what is our optimal strategy to find $(x_m,y_m)$, where the value $f(x_m,y_m) = M$ is obtained?  Provided this optimal strategy, and letting $(x_i,y_i)$ be the current "best guess" for $(x_m,y_m)$ after $i$ queries, how close is $f(x_i,y_i)$ to $M$?

What if we guarantee rotational symmetry for $f$ about its maximum at the point $(x_m,y_m)$?

__

Short (hopefully intuitive) description: A blind hiker is climbing a mountain, where the mountain's topographic profile can be described as strictly convex.  However, all the hiker can do is decide to walk back and forth along a straight-line of his choice until he maximizes his altitude (with the help of some altimeter instrument which is a bit noisy s.t. he is only guaranteed to be within some fraction $\omega$ of this maximum).  He can then decide to walk along another straight-line trajectory, of his choice, performing the same task.  What is his best approach to converge near the summit of the mountain using the fewest straight-line paths?  What if the mountain has rotational symmetry with respect to a pole planted and standing vertically at its peak?

Comment: Just to make sure: you want to maximize a convex function? (and not minimize)